# Looping through input variables and printing in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, loops, shell, date

Hi pls I'm new to shell scripting. I need to write a shell script that will ask for 2 parameters, one for startdate and another for number of days.

Then loop from start date to number of days and print each date.
E.g 16-09-2022 and 4 will print:
16-09-2022
17-09-2022
18-09-2022
19-09-2022

Tried this:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "enter date"
read var1

echo "enter no of days"
read var2

for i in {0..$var2..1}
do
 echo $i $var1   
(here's where I'm trying to figure how to increment the dates)
done
```

Thanks

Comment: PLease read the guide https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html, try to write a script and come up with question if you still have any. Unfortunately here is not a place where others programm it for you.

Comment: @m19v Yh I've tried stuff out, just trying to figure how to print the datetype incrementally

Comment: Please add your script to the description of question and write what is not working.

Comment: Please check the answer below. If you think the answer is what you have tried to figure out, consider accepting and/or voting up the answer. For further information about voting and accepting the answers check https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Save the script below in file, name it e.g. `get-started-with-bash-by-example.sh` and run it as follows:

```bash
bash get-started-with-bash-by-example.sh 2022-09-25 10
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# USAGE:
# ${SCRIPT_NAME} args
#       arg1 - date (must be in format 'yyyy-mm-dd')
#       arg2 - number of days to add
# 
# EXAMPLES
#    ${SCRIPT_NAME} 2022-09-25 10

for i in $(seq "$2")
do
    date +%d-%m-%Y -d "$1 + $i day"
done
```

Or with user input:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter start-date in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format: " startdate
read -p "Enter number of days to add: " nofdaystoadd

for i in $(seq "$nofdaystoadd")
do
    date +%d-%m-%Y -d "$startdate + $i day"
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
26-09-2022
27-09-2022
28-09-2022
29-09-2022
30-09-2022
01-10-2022
02-10-2022
03-10-2022
04-10-2022
05-10-2022
```

I hope this example helps you to get started with bash.